# in AppDelegate.persistentContainer.getter: Error occurred when I changed an attribute type from String to Date in CoreData.(SwiftUI)

Tags: swift, core-data

Thread 1: Fatal error: Unresolved error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134140 "Persistent store migration failed, missing mapping model."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change your data model, Core Data tries to migrate existing data to use the new model. In many cases that's automatic. But it doesn't know how to convert a string to a date, so it gives up and shows this error.

If this app is still in development, just delete the app from the phone or simulator and reinstall it. If it's released, you'll need to learn about [model migration](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/Introduction.html) so that you can tell Core Data how you want strings to be converted to dates.

Comment: I created a new model from Editor -> Add model version, then I saw all attributes in the new model and I set it as default version, but the problem still there. Maybe I just have to create a new CoreData project with model I need and copy my code inside it.

Comment: Making the new model version isn’t enough because Core Data still doesn’t know how you want to convert strings to dates. It can’t be automatic, you need to write some code to do it.

Comment: Also like I said, if you don’t have existing data you need to migrate, just delete the app from the phone or simulator and then reinstall with the new model.

Comment: Yes, thank you. It is working now after I deleted the App from my iphone.